# Rails 4 railties's executable "rails" conflicts with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm, bundler

I have rails 4 and that's my default version (and I still wants it to be). but I d'like to add rails 3.2 on my computer. 
On the following command: `gem install rails -v 3.2.16`

I have this Warning:

```
railties's executable "rails" conflicts with rails
Overwrite the executable? [yN]
```

I d'like to know if this will cause some bugs to my 4.0.1?

Comment: You should use `rvm` and install rails 3 into a new `gemset`

Comment: thks majoia! so what is the process to install it. cause  from the documentation rvm will give me a separeted gem directory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use rvm and install rails 3 into a new gemset. Exactly do steps as follows:

1. [Install `rvm`](https://rvm.io/rvm/install).
2. Install or use a ruby:

   ```
   rvm install ruby-2.0.0
   ```
3. Create a *gemset*, and then use it:

   ```
   rvm gemset create rails_1_app
   rvm gemset use rails_1_app
   ```
4. Install bunlder:

   ```
   gem install bundler
   ```
5. Create **Gemfile**, and specify *rails* 4 in it:

   ```
   gem 'rails', '~> 4.0'
   ```
6. Install requires gems:

   ```
   bundle install
   ```
7. Repeat steps 3-6 for a new gemset, but specifying *rails* 3 in it:

   ```
   gem 'rails', '~> 3.0'
   ```

Comment: Thks majioa I need to ask for a presicion I have already ruby 2.0.0 and rails 4 installed. Do I have to start at the #3 to 7 only once? or should I do 1-6+3-7?

Comment: you can omit first 3-6 point, but gem set you will have the `default` one.

Comment: thks majoia for the precision!