# Nokogiri not installing as a gem even though it's listed in Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler, gemfile

Nokogiri isn't installing even though it's listed in the Gemfile. Help?

```
[root@mongo p]# cat Gemfile
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.12'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'jquery-rails'


# ============================
# Gems
# ============================
gem 'whois'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'bson_ext'
gem 'bson'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'rpm_contrib'
gem 'savon'


# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end


# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger (ruby-debug for Ruby 1.8.7+, ruby-debug19 for Ruby 1.9.2+)
# gem 'ruby-debug'
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

# Bundle the extra gems:
# gem 'bj'
# gem 'nokogiri'
# gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
# gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'

# Bundle gems for the local environment. Make sure to
# put test-only gems in this group so their generators
# and rake tasks are available in development mode:
# group :development, :test do
#   gem 'webrat'
# end



[root@mongo p]# bundle install
Using rake (10.1.0)
Using i18n (0.6.4)
Using multi_json (1.7.7)
Using activesupport (3.2.12)
Using builder (3.0.4)
Using activemodel (3.2.12)
Using erubis (2.7.0)
Using journey (1.0.4)
Using rack (1.4.5)
Using rack-cache (1.2)
Using rack-test (0.6.2)
Using hike (1.2.3)
Using tilt (1.4.1)
Using sprockets (2.2.2)
Using actionpack (3.2.12)
Using mime-types (1.23)
Using polyglot (0.3.3)
Using treetop (1.4.14)
Using mail (2.4.4)
Using actionmailer (3.2.12)
Using arel (3.0.2)
Using tzinfo (0.3.37)
Using activerecord (3.2.12)
Using activeresource (3.2.12)
Using gyoku (1.0.0)
Using akami (1.2.0)
Using bson (1.9.0)
Using bson_ext (1.9.0)
Using coffee-script-source (1.6.2)
Using execjs (1.4.0)
Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
Using rack-ssl (1.3.3)
Using json (1.8.0)
Using rdoc (3.12.2)
Using thor (0.18.1)
Using railties (3.2.12)
Using coffee-rails (3.2.2)
Using httpi (2.0.2)
Using jquery-rails (3.0.1)
Using mysql2 (0.3.11)
Using newrelic_rpm (3.6.4.122)
Using nori (2.1.0)
Using bundler (1.3.1)
Using rails (3.2.12)
Using rpm_contrib (2.1.11)
Using sass (3.2.9)
Using sass-rails (3.2.6)
Using wasabi (3.1.0)
Using savon (2.2.0)
Using uglifier (2.1.1)
Using whois (3.1.3)
Your bundle is complete! It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
```

Comment: remove **Gemfile.lock** and try again

Comment: and please dont use *root* account, use `rvm` to install gems into gemsets

Comment: removing Gemfile.lock didn't help ... other suggestions? thanks!

Comment: bundler recreated **Gemfle.lock** again, please verify, is there *nokogiri* gem in it?

Comment: yes the gem is listed in Gemfile.lock

Comment: type `bundle show nokogiri`

Comment: [cp]# bundle show nokogiri
Cannot write a changed lockfile while frozen.
Could not find gem 'nokogiri'.
Did you mean nokogiri?

Comment: that is key: `Cannot write a changed lockfile` you haven't recreated lock file.

Comment: the main root of problem is that you use bundler under *root*

Comment: this error only started after posting this question ... we have been trying different things and caused this to happen just now.

Comment: what should we use bundler under?

Comment: under progrmmer user, or under runner user. I advice programmer user. also to separate space from other project use rvm: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20899772/rails-4-railtiess-executable-rails-conflicts-with-rails/20899995#20899995

Comment: `bundle show nokogiri` must not answer this that error. It shell to show path to nokogiri gem, or answer that the gem isn't installed

Comment: we solved it finally by running bundle install --no-deployment

Comment: could you add this as an answer then we can credit you? thanks!

Comment: ok, but this `bundle install --no-deployment` sounds as a cheat... , and I strongly advice you not using the root.

Comment: ok we'll take your advice. could you please put this all into an answer? then we can credit you! thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please at first remove **Gemfile.lock** file to make sure that bundle rebuild all dependencies, and install all gem as for a first time, and recreate the file, then:

```
$ bundle install
```

Please verify, that the *nokogiri* gem has presented in the **Gemfile.lock**. Then to make sure that the *nokogiri* gem is properly installed type:

```
$ bundle show nokogiri
/path/to/nokogiri/gem
```

I above command shows an error others to *Could not find gem 'nokogiri'* that means that the setup of your systems is incorrect. So please don't use root account, and use simple user as holder of the project. And to separate project gem versions from each other use `rvm` to install gems into its gemsets as it has been written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20899772/rails-4-railtiess-executable-rails-conflicts-with-rails/20899995#20899995).